# Is there a way to change the shape of a shared variable in Theano?

Tags: python, theano

I can't seem to find any information on this, which implies I'm thinking about shared variables in the wrong way...

I understand you can use get_value() and set_value(), so I can do

```
>>> x = theano.shared(np.array(([1,2,3])))
>>> x.get_value()
array([1,2,3])
>>> x.set_value(np.append(x.get_value(),4))
>>> x.get_value()
array([1,2,3,4])
```

but I can't do, for example

```
>>> x.set_value(np.vstack((x.get_value(),x.get_value())))
```

as this results in a TypeError for the wrong number of dimensions. I'm iterating over a function that takes two matrices as part of the calculation, but I would like to only pass through parts of the matrices to the function, varying in shape (imagine a neural network where nodes are randomly removed for a given iteration). Is it possible to do this with without redefining the shared variables, the calculation, and the function for each iteration?

Comment: You are not only chaning the shape, but also the number of dimendions. Try declaring it as `np.random.rand(1,3)` the first time. Or with other `1xN` vector. (Can't test it right now, but it might help). It will tell theano that it is 2-dimensional and should let you extend it in both dimensions.

Comment: Ah that works! Thanks a lot for taking the time :)